# IDEA doesnt want to use NotNull from javax, but instead use org.jetbrains

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, jetbrains-ide, notnull

I was setuping my project when saw this on @NotNull annotation in my DTOs

```
Not 'javax.validation.constraints.NotNull' but 'org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull' would be used for code generation
```

I have import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

But still see this warning.

Why IDEA dont want to use javax NotNull and what should I do to force it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When you compile your project, the IDE adds assertions to all methods and parameters annotated with the @NotNull annotation. The assertions will fail if null is passed in code where @NotNull is expected. You can disable this option and configure the list of annotations in the **Settings/Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S. Go to Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler**.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html

Maybe this would to the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to maio290 's answer, it's important you change the "annotiation used for code generation" setting: [image: screenshot of configure nullability/nonnull annotatioons dialog]